# Read the mobile version of a web page in htmlunit

Tags: java, mobile, browser, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am trying to access a web page in java using **htmlunit** libraries. I can successfully read the page for the regular desktop browsers, but now I want to read the mobile version of the same web pages, basically the raw HTML that would appear in the cellphone browser, but I can't.

I tried to define a new `BrowserVersion` class with a mobile phone specifications, such as the following. But when I read the webpages, the read values are not the mobile version of the webpage (It is same as desktop version of the webpage).

```
    String applicationName = "Chrome";
    String applicationVersion = "5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19";
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19";
    int browserVersionNumeric = 51;
    BrowserVersion browser = new BrowserVersion(applicationName, applicationVersion, userAgent, browserVersionNumeric);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(browser);
```

Any body can help me to read the mobile version of a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- it is always a good idea to use the latest snapshot of HtmlUnit. For your case you will face a major interface change because the way of creating a newer browser version was changed.
- i guess you webpage might take the screen size into account
- maybe the pages are the same only the css takes care of the screen size, you get only differetn visual results